# Second mariadb+phpmyadmin Docker container access denied

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have working mariadb+phpmyadmin container on my local dev computer.
I would like to create another mariadb+phpmyadmin container, but I'm getting error: [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES).
I can't figure out where is a problem. I tried to add parameter: `MYSQL_HOST: '%'` and modify line:
`test: mysqladmin ping -h $$MYSQL_HOST -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD`
but still no success.

Working docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  rosetta_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  maria_db_service:
    image: mariadb:10.5.9
    container_name: 'rosetta-api-db'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'rosetta'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    networks:
      - rosetta_net
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5

  phpmyadmin_service:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1
    container_name: 'rosetta-api-db-admin'
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db_server
      MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 3600
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 128M
    depends_on:
      maria_db_service:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/phpmyadmin/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - db_rosetta_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - rosetta_net

volumes:
  db_rosetta_data:
```

Not working docker-compose.yml (it is very similar to previous one):

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  parkovisko_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  maria_db_service:
    image: mariadb:10.5.9
    container_name: 'parkovisko-api-db'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'parkovisko'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    networks:
      - parkovisko_net
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5

  phpmyadmin_service:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1
    container_name: 'parkovisko-api-db-admin'
    ports:
      - '8083:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db_server
      MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 3600
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 128M
    depends_on:
      maria_db_service:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/phpmyadmin/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - db_parkovisko_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - parkovisko_net

volumes:
  db_parkovisko_data:
```

Comment: I am not a docker pro but I had some issues with a similar scenario too. I ended up doing the following: (1) I "exposed" the mariadb port (as I didn't see a need to make it available outside docker, didn't map it with "ports" to somewhere else. (2) I set the phpmyadmin PMA_HOST variable to the exact name of my mariadb-service name (in your first example, would be maria_db_service). It didn't connect properly otherwise. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same volumes for both of the docker-compose files, so MYSQL cant initialize mounting the same volumes for 2 containers

There are multiple ways to fix this:

Change it to named volumes:

```
volumes:
 - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Copy the data to another folder with cp and then mount it again (assuming you want the same data on both containers).

The same applies to .cnf and phpmyadmin containers